# Please simplify $((p \land f) \lor q) \land t$ and prove correctness of your simplification.

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to simplify this expression, and I got the following:

$$((p \land f)\lor q) \land t= (((p\land f)\lor q)\land t)
           =(t \land (p\land f))\lor (q\land t)$$

would this be the simplified version. I'd appreciate some explaining. Thanks

Comment: I edited your formulas using proper mathematical typesetting. Please hit edit to see how this works. THere is also a Mathjax tutorial for some of the basic typesetting commands. Welcome to Math.SE!

Comment: I am pretty sure the $f$ is supposed to be $False$, and the $t$ is $True$ ... otherwise there would not be much to do in terms of simplifying ... Let's assume I am correct .. can you simplify things more now?

Comment: @Bram28 you should be able to simplify via distributivity

Comment: @Mark And that is what the OP did, yes.... is it simpler?  Debatable ... for some applications we do do indeed want the more 'flattened' formulas, but for other purposes we may want the 'shortest' one ... I guess 'simplest' is a bit of an ambiguous term. Frankly, I am still struck by the presence of an $f$ and a $t$ ... with $p$ and $q$ the 'typical' variables, I would find it improbably that $t$ and $f$ would be just some pther variables ... so I really think they are meant as the True and False. And *now* you can *really* simplify this expression! (and in the end you know you have t answer!)

Comment: OK @Ash, you'll need to show a little responsiveness ...

Comment: @Bram28 the instructor used **f** and **t** as variables rather than whether they should be **true** or **false**. I wanted to get a simplified expression then represent it in a truth table, but wanted to confirm that this is as simplified as I can get it. And thanks for editing my question.

Comment: @Ash Ok, that surprises me, but I'll take your word for it. Well, then I think the Distribution you did is really the only thing you can do.  As I said in an earlier comment, it is not clear to me that that really 'simplifies' things, but ok. And yes, to demonstrate that you did thing right you do need to put both expressions on a truth table.  How many rows?

Comment: @Bram28, I have designed my table with 8 rows, one row for each of the following, **f, t, q, p, (p∧f), t∧(p∧f), (q∧t), (t∧(p∧f))∨(q∧t)**

Comment: @Bram28, actually I can do this into two tables, one for **(t∧(p∧f))** and another for **(q∧t)** then a third table for **(t∧(p∧f))∨(q∧t)** combining the outcome of the two previous tables

Comment: @Ash Those would be the *columns*, not the rows. ALso, I am a little concerned that you make three separate tables, rather than one 'combined' table that has multiple columns .. make sure you do the latter!

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, you're right. I got a table of 128 rows

Comment: @Ash No, you have $4$ variables, so you only have $2^4=16$ rows.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to simplify this expression, and I got the following:
>
> $$((p \land f)\lor q) \land t ~{=~ (((p\land f)\lor q)\land t)
>            \\ =~(t \land (p\land f))\lor (q\land t)}$$
>
> would this be the simplified version. I'd appreciate some explaining. Thanks

That is okay.   Whether this is simpler or not is *debatable*, as you have increased the count of literals and operators.   However, you have reduced the *depth* of nesting and arrived at the *Distributed Normal Form*:   $(p\wedge f\wedge t)\vee (q\wedge t)$

You can also easily put it into the *Conjunctive Normal Form*:   $(p\vee q)\wedge (f\vee q)\wedge t$

It is a matter of perspective, but there is a certain elegance to the Normal Forms, and they are at least easy to compare and evaluate.